# Remove flex license key from Flex builder 3

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

I had installed flex builder 3 plug-in in Eclispe 3.4. Now the license is expired. So i need to add another license into the same. But i could not able to change the license key because the option is disabled.

So please any have idea how to change the license key in eclipse with flex builder plug-in 3.

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the license expired".  Flex Builder 3 licenses bought from Adobe should not expire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=configuring_environment_2.html), I think you should correct license.properties file for your needs.

If you'll fail in this, try to reinstall your plugin.

Regards
Eugene